# How can I stop Microsoft Word (for Mac) from printing double sided by default?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, printing, printer

My MS Word (2016) for Mac suddendly started printing every document double sided by default - which I do not want ;)

Essentially, when I choose Print, it is selected by default on "Long-Edge binding" in the "Two-sided" option.
File > Print > Copies & Pages > Layout > Two-sided > Long-Edge binding

Every time, I have to manually turn it off to get basic, single page printing.

The printer settings (Canon TS6161) seem fine, and it does that nowhere else - pdf, Word for Windows etc. Only my Word for Mac.

Any idea how to change it or reset the default printing settings for Word?

Thanks for any suggestions and have a great day :)
Vincent

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKgnp.png)

Comment: Wouldn't know for Mac, but the setting you're looking for is called "duplex" printing, if that helps?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Comment: ok, noted. ----

Comment: Maybe you could change the default value by CUPS, which is the core printing system of OS X. Reference: [How to Stop Two-Side Printing From Being the Default in macOS](https://www.howtogeek.com/309677/how-to-stop-two-side-printing-from-being-the-default-in-macos/). Similar thread: [How to STOP default two sided printing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5244577).